# How do I get the orange crystals?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

How do I get to the orange crystal for the quest [Crystals and Moonlight](http://lotro.mmodb.com/quests/crystals-and-moonlight-3143.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11.2s 111.1w in the Silvertine Lodes zone is the location.

It's in the goblin camp, you get there when you go from the nearby dwarfen camp (don't remember it's name, something with deep i think) down and at the bottom of the way is left a way further down to the goblin camp and right is a way through the rocks to the other crystals. Take the left path and try to get to the far right side of the goblin camp. There is a shortcut through the rocks on the right side of the way to the camp (There is also a quest-dwarf there).

Comment: and I get there how? that zone has many z/vertical levels.

Comment: It's in the goblin camp, you get there when you go from the nearby dwarfen camp (don't remember it's name, something with deep i think) down and at the bottom of the way is left a way further down to the goblin camp and right is a way through the rocks to the other crystals. Take the left path and try to get to the far right side of the goblin camp. There is a shortcut through the rocks on the right side of the way to the camp (There is also a quest-dwarf there).